# Why Spring RestTemplate is not a Bean by default in Spring?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

When using REST calls in Spring Boot project, and as I'm lazy guy, my hands quickly go to keyboard to write a config for a Spring's RestTemplate like this one:

```
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
```

This is in order not to instanciate it every time.
Why don't we have it configured as a Bean by default?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why don't we have it configured as a Bean by default?

Even though it might be a little bit annoying the Spring Boot Team has a good reason to not declare a `RestTemplate` as a `@Bean` by default. It is explained in the Reference Documentation at the [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-resttemplate) section as follows:

> Since `RestTemplate` instances often need to be customized before being used, Spring Boot does not provide any single auto-configured `RestTemplate` bean.
>
> It does, however, auto-configure a `RestTemplateBuilder`, which can be used to create RestTemplate instances when needed

---

For the new `WebClient` Spring Boot creates only `WebClient.Builder` for the same reason (Thanks to [Darren Forsythe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7554328/darren-forsythe) for pointing out) - for more details see the [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient) section